HOW TO UNDERSTAND EVENT AND LISTENER
I could not understand the concept of event and listener while learning.
How can I understand the concept of event and listener? Is there any documentation I can read?

To understand the concept of event in Solidity, you can refer to the following docs:

Solidity official documentation section on events.

Solidity by Example documentation on events.


Example Contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Example {
    event ValueChanged(address indexed caller, uint256 oldValue, uint256 newValue);

    uint256 public value;

    function setValue(uint256 _value) public {
        uint256 oldValue = value; // Store the old value
        value = _value; // Update the state variable

        // Emit the event after the state change
        emit ValueChanged(msg.sender, oldValue, _value);
    }
}

Explanation
1. Event Declaration
event ValueChanged(address indexed caller, uint256 oldValue, uint256 newValue);


Event Keyword: event is used to define an event in Solidity. It is similar to defining a function but is intended to log information when something significant happens.

Event Name: The event is named ValueChanged. You can name it anything you like, and typically, it should describe what has happened.

Parameters:

address indexed caller: The indexed keyword makes this parameter searchable. It refers to the address of the person (or contract) who called the function that emits this event.
uint256 oldValue: This stores the old value of the value variable before it was changed.
uint256 newValue: This stores the new value that is being set.



2. What Happens When the Function is Called?

When setValue is called, the following sequence occurs:

The old value of the state variable value is stored in a local variable oldValue.

The state variable value is updated to _value.

The event ValueChanged is emitted, logging the msg.sender (caller’s address), the oldValue (value before the change), and _value (the new value).




Example of a Listener (Off-chain)
Here's how you might listen for this event off-chain using ethers.js:
// Assuming you have a contract instance
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);

// Listen for the ValueChanged event
contract.on("ValueChanged", (author, oldValue, newValue) => {
    console.log(`Value changed by ${author}: ${oldValue} -> ${newValue}`);
});


Listener: This JavaScript code listens for the ValueChanged event.

Reacting to Events: Whenever the ValueChanged event is emitted (whenever setValue is called), this listener will trigger, and you can see the logged message indicating who changed the value and what the old and new values are.



I have read them. Could you please explain using something I can relate with? I meant something in physical experience

I've added some explanation with example. Please check.
